# How do I prove that if $\text{gcd}(m,n) \neq 1$, the result is $p$ or $q$ in RSA?

Tags: rsa, factoring

I understand that $\text{gcd}(m,n)$ needs to be $1$ so we can apply the Euler's theorem, and if it's not $1$, the result is one of the prime factors of $n$. But Why the result it is always $p$ or $q$? Couldn't it be any other number?

Comment: It's pretty much a no brainer, because $p$ and $q$ are by definition the factors of $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m$ and $n$ be products of two primes as in RSA:
$n=pq$ and $ m = rs$.

if $m=n$ then we cannot learn about the primes,

if $m\not= n$ and $\gcd(m,n) >1$:
since $m\not =n$ then $1<\gcd(m,n) < \min(m,n)$
gcd is the max of  divisors sets intersection $D_n=\{1,p,q,n\}$ and $D_m = \{1,r,s,m\}$ hence we know now the $ \gcd(m,n) \in \{p,q\}\cap \{r,s\}\subset\{p,q,r,s\}$ hence the gcd returns a prime divisor of $n$ and $m$.

Answer (score 0):

A positive $d'$ with $d'\mid n$ and $d'\mid x$ is called **a common divisor** and the greatest of them is called the **greatest common divisor** $d = \gcd(x,n)$.

Since $n$ is the product of two distinct primes, then any common divisor must divide $n$. By the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), the prime factorization of $n$ is unique (up to order), namely $n=p\cdot q$

Therefore any common divisor of $x$ and $n$ must divide at least one of $1,p,q,pq=n$.

- $1$ iff $p\not\mid x$ or $q\not\mid x$
- $p$ if $p \mid x$ and $q \not\mid x$
- $q$ if $q \mid x$ and $p \not\mid x$
- $n$ if $x \equiv 0 \bmod n$

as a conclusion $\gcd(x,n) \in \{1,p,q,n\}$